# How do i parse images from response body in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, http, response, fastapi

My application consists of a python server and a Flutter client. I intend to send a list of images from the flutter client to the python server, do some operations on them (such as flipping, resizing), then send the processed images back right away. I have my code as the following:

**Server**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile
from typing_extensions import List
from PIL import Image
import io

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/process')
async def upload_images(files: List[UploadFile]):
    imgs = []
    for f in files:
        contents = await f.read()
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(contents))
        # do something with image
        # ...
        imgs.append(image)
    return imgs


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

**Client**

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

void main() async {
  const String url = "http://localhost:8000/process";
  var request = MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse(url));

  var image = File('image.jpg');
  request.files.add(await MultipartFile.fromPath('files',image.path));
  request.files.add(await MultipartFile.fromPath('files',image.path));

  final response = await request.send();
  var responseBytes = await response.stream.toBytes();
  exit(0);
}
```

With the above code, I managed to send a list of images to the client, but I have no idea how to parse the returned results?
Is there any way to send the image contents back, and store the them to a list of **File** (so that I can save or display them) in Flutter?

The *responseBytes* mentioned above is the furthest thing I ever got. I have tried several way but none of them worked.

Comment: I got "flutter: {content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8, date: Thu, 24 Aug 2023 15:10:40 GMT, content-length: 21, server: uvicorn}".

Answer (score -1):

You can store the image files in different ways.

**Dynamic list**,
 where the list of images is stored temporarily in a variable. The constraint in this method is that this is very memory intensive, especially if you are storing multiple images or heavy image data, but if you don't need a big cache, this is very efficient and faster than using files, but images are lost when you close the app.

**Using local storage.** 
You can use a library to store the images locally, and then open them as you need them. This requires managing the CRUD functions for file management.

**Using libraries like Hive**
This might be my favorite method as we speak.
Hive allows a key-value storage and abstracts you from knowing the exact location or file names, you just need to create a `key: value` list and store it in a hive box. The files will be saved locally and can be accessed at any time.